# Gulp browserify JS but replace revision references like gulp-usemin

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, grunt-usemin, gulp-sourcemaps

So I've used gulp-usemin for a while and generally like it.  In particular, I love the built in cache-busting ability

**Before**

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script3.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**Run**

```
return gulp.src( './public/index.html')
    .pipe( usemin({
        js: [uglify(), rev()]
    }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./dist') );
```

**After**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app-d8ce9cc5.js"></script>
```

However, recently I've been using browserify, which builds the source tree via node-style `require` statements.

**Before**

```
// index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

// js/app.js
require('angular');
require('./ngmodules/customFilters');
require('./components/feature/feature');
```

**Run**

```
return browserify( './public/js/app.js' )
    .bundle()
    .pipe( source('bundle.js') ) 
    .pipe( streamify(uglify()) )
    .pipe( buffer() )
    .pipe( rev() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./dist/js') )
```

**After**

```
// index.html (no reference update)
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
```

The problem is if I use `rev` I have no  ability to hash/cachebust the file.  Is there any way to use the two in tandem?  Or a an easy way to point my `dist/index.html` reference to `bundle.js` to the hashed version?  I've read the [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/blob/master/integration.md) recommendations but they seem horrible in comparison.

For context, I'm using Python/Django/Jade/Sass/Compass in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to use `gulp-inject` rather than `gulp-usemin`

**Before**

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

**Run**

```
var jsStream = browserify( POINT_OF_ENTRY )
    .bundle()
    .pipe( source('bundle.js' ) )
    .pipe( streamify( uglify() ) )
    .pipe( streamify( rev() ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( PATHS.dest.js ));

return gulp.src( PATHS.src.html )
    .pipe( inject(jsStream) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( DIST ) );
```

**After**

```
<script src="/js/bundle-b2fbae2b.js"></script>
```